# "Up to" for a minimum

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction

I'm trying to say that a temperature can reach -*X* °C as a minimum, in a sentence that would look like

> ... with temperatures *up to* 40 °C.

for a maximum.

For what I've seen "**down to**" doesn't apply for this kind of sentence, but I'm not sure.

So what is the "up to" equivalent for a minimum ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with "down to."

Answer (score 1):

Usually we use "as low as" as the opposite of "up to".

> Temperatures tonight will reach *as low as* -40 °C.

Comment: According to ngram, "as high as" and "as low as" are more common ways of saying the same thing as "up to" and "down to." "As high as" is slightly more common than "up to" whereas "as low as" is considerably more common than "down to." Thus the answer is perfectly correct in saying "more usual," but it should not then be inferred that "down to" is an unusual or strange locution. Although I cannot prove it, I suspect that "up to" and down to" are far more common in speech than ngram indicates.

Comment: So does it apply when we talk about temperatures that can be -40 °C as well as much more (like 50 °C) ? Because when I read this, I would understand that : the temperatures are generally cold, but tonight they may reach a minimum of -40 °C ; yet my question is about general cases, where the temperatures can be much higher but we only know the minimum.

Comment: @JeffMorrow: NGrams are not definitive proof of anything her regarding the OP's construction ("temperatures up to"). There are too many other constructions that involve "up to" and "down to"; read [this posting about NGram usage on SE sites](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2469/should-we-allow-google-ngrams-to-be-presented-as-statistical-evidence-without-qu).

Comment: I certainly did not say that Ngrams were definitive proof of something. In fact, I explicitly pointed out that Ngrams cannot capture patterns of common speech. Are you seriously saying that no one would say "The weather forecast says it is going down to zero tonight." Or are you trying to say that "down to" cannot be used with minima whereas "up to" may be used with maxima? If so, please give your citations.

Comment: @JeffMorrow: Please don't get all defensive. I'm just pointing something out that needs to be pointed out from time to time. And I'm certainly not saying that no one would say "going down to zero"; in fact, that was one of the cases I was thinking of that is excluded by your NGram citation.

Comment: @Robusto Now I am truly lost. Whatever in my Ngram comment excluded "down to zero." Curious, not defensive.

Comment: I said it excluded "going down to zero" and I actually meant to say that would be a valid reference in this case; the point is, some versions of "down to" *are* included and should not be **for this purpose**, e.g., "He went down to the store." That has nothing to do with the maxima/minima discussion. Did you read the link I posted above? It lists some common failings of NGrams you might find interesting.